# Alternative to HttpRequestMessage SetContext method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have this code from codeplex

```
private async Task ExecuteChangeSet(
        ChangeSetRequestItem changeSet,
        IList<ODataBatchResponseItem> responses,
        CancellationToken cancellation)
{
        ChangeSetResponseItem changeSetResponse;

        // Create a new ShoppingContext instance, associate it with each of the requests, start a new
        // transaction, execute the changeset and then commit or rollback the transaction depending on
        // whether the responses were all successful or not.
        using (ShoppingContext context = new ShoppingContext())
        {
            foreach (HttpRequestMessage request in changeSet.Requests)
            {
                request.SetContext(context);
            }
```

The complete sample code can be found [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataEFBatchSample/ODataEFBatchSample/).
I downloaded the project and it is using .net framework 4.5
but in .NET Framework 4.6.1 the SetContext method is no longer present
I want to know how can I achieve the same in framework version 4.6.1? 
I am basically creating a OData V3 Service which will be hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with creating your own functionality for setting the context and retrieve it where needed, with HttpRequestMessage extensions like:

Example class:

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
     private const string Context = "ShoppingContext";
     public static void SetContext(this HttpRequestMessage request, ShoppingContext context)
    {
        request.Properties[Context] = context;
    }

    public static ShoppingContext GetContext(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        object context;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(Context, out context))
        {
            return (ShoppingContext) context;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Setting context
request.SetContext(context);
//reading context
var context = request.GetContext();
```

Comment: I actually have that code since it is part of the sample code. I was actually wondering about its usage. 

I don't think I understand? The usage that you mentioned is actually the same code as I posted above. Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Ok it's actually my fault I have different name space in the extension class. the other batch class has iPOSServiceV3.Extension name space while the extension has iPOSServiceV3.Extensions name space. After correcting the name space its all working fine now.

Comment: Actually, upon seeing this https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs gave me an idea that my code should work.